# Specify build directory name

Tags: msbuild

I need project to be built into folder:

```
\bin\Debug 1.0.3.4
```

Where `1.0.3.4` is a current building assembly version specified in `assembly: AssemblyVersion` attribute.
I tried using different variables like `$(AssemblyVersion)`, `GetAssemblyIdentity` task but had no luck.. I'm not so good at using MSBuild.

Comment: What is the output path attribute specified in the debug configuration of your csproj file?

Comment: Do you mean the `1.0.3.4` number is only available as a string inside a .cs file?

Comment: In your csproj, you should be able to find the output path attribute in your debug configuration. What is the value of it? Unload your project, edit the csproj, and Ctrl+F "<OutputPath>"

Comment: @stijn, the 1.0.3.4 is specified in his AssemblyInfo.cs file under the AssemblyVersion attribute

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that - sorry I wasn't clear enough: should the output folder be determined based on the version string found in the AssemblyVersion attribute in the cs file, or do you already have an actually built dll with that version number and the version should be extracted from that dll?

Comment: I guess you could also try to set the output path attribute to
<OutputPath> \bin\Debug $(ApplicationVersion) </OutputPath>

Comment: @Chirac ApplicationVersion is not some kind of built-in property you can access, the key is getting that ApplicationVersion value not applying it

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution to this is to, *after* the build, use `GetAssemblyIdentity` to extract the version info and then move the `$(TargetFile)` to the appropriate directory.

This assumes you don't have any dependencies going on. Otherwise, you'll need to modify the `$(TargetPath)`, `$(TargetName)`, and `$(TargetExt)` or go with the "proper" way of doing it - modifying `$(OutputPath)` dynamically.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyIdentity"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Version>@(AssemblyIdentity->'%(Version)')</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)$(Version)" />
  </Target>
```

The proper way would be to modify `$(OutDir)` aka `$(OutputPath)`, but that would involve things like modifying the AssemblyVersion.cs file (or more complexly, a copy of it injected automatically into the build chain).

You could also instead parse the version from the AssemblyVersion.cs file.